# How do I remove a working copy created via git-new-workdir without hosing the original repo?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm using the git-new-workdir script present in contrib section of git's codebase: https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/workdir to work with multiple branches of the same code base simultaneously. This is on windows, using msysgit and the repo is a git svn repo and not pure git. 
I have no problem creating working copies using this command by saying:

```
git-new-workdir original-working-copy new-working-copy branch-name-to-checkout
```

But when I'm no longer interested in the branch and I want to get rid of the working copy, doing an `rm -rfR new-working-copy` also hoses the original-working-copy.

In hind sight, that is kinda obvious, given that git-new-workdir uses hard links to share the same .git repo between multiple working copies.

What is a good way to clean up working copies created this way, which I no longer want on my machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On normal UNIX systems, `git-new-workdir` uses symlinks to share everything with the original repo, and so you can simply `rm -rf new-working-copy` to delete the new workdir and everything is fine.

I have no idea what might be different about msysgit that would change this.

---

Turns out, as noted in the comments, that the issue is that `rm` on Windows uses `del`, which actually recurses into symlinks. Deleting a symlink itself requires `rmdir`.

Comment: It's on windows and it uses mklink to create the link.

Comment: @Rohith: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link), `mklink` produces a symbolic link that functions much as it does on UNIX. So given that, you should be able to just `rm -rf new-workdir` and it should work fine. If you look at `new-workdir/.git` you should see everything in there, except for `HEAD`, `index`, and `logs`, is a symbolic link.

Comment: A bit more googling and it looks like windows has some interesting quirks. See this: http://superuser.com/questions/167076/windows-7-delete-symbolic-link - I think this could explain why an rm -rfR was hosing my original .git folder. I might have to use rmdir instead here.

Comment: @Rohith: Yeah, that definitely sounds like it.

Comment: Tried it out, this worked. Created a bat file to remove the symlinks inside the .git dir using del or rmdir depending on whether they are directories or files.

Comment: Could you please post a sample of the .bat file you made? I understand what you are doing but I am having trouble visualizing it in a .bat.

Answer (score 1):

As requested in the comments, here is the batch file I'm using.

```
cd %1\.git
del HEAD
del config
rmdir hooks
del index
rmdir svn
rmdir refs
del packed-refs
rmdir objects
del remotes
del rr-cache
rmdir info
rmdir logs\refs
del logs\HEAD
rmdir logs
cd ..
rmdir .git
cd ..
```